# Is it possible to do a POST directly from an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to allow recipients of an email to submit a POST request which will have the effect of "liking" something.

It's clear how you create a GET request in an email (add an href). Is it possible to get (or make the server think it's received) a POST request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed a form in your email and set its method to "post", but you shouldn't assume that email clients will render forms correctly, or at all. Many email providers like Google, Yahoo and Hotmail will show ugly warnings about submitting data to 3rd parties when you attempt to submit a form inside an email.

A JavaScript solution is less likely to work, so much so that it doesn't bear discussion.

In short, "yes", but not at all reliably.

Comment: Thanks meager. I think the easiest solution is just going to be to handle it on the server instead. Not really a biggie

Comment: Yep.  Unique links on Like and Dislike images that do a normal GET (say for a particular user:  http://example.com/api/email/12345612394 generated for like and http://example.com/api/email/841438418471 generated for dislike) will probably be more compatible. Does require more backend, but should be worth it.